# when are local quasigeodesics global in CAT(0)

Tags: gr.group-theory, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

It is well-known (and easily shown) that a local quasi-geodesic (for some value of "local") in a $\delta$-hyperbolic space is global (one can compute the constants, as well, from local data). This is false in CAT(0) (think of Euclidean space), but there must be some condition under which it is true. A quick virtual leafing through Bridson-Haefliger brought no joy. (the hidden agenda is figuring out when ping-pong type free subgroups are quasi-isometrically embedded, and with what distortion). Any pointers?

Comment: I know examples of ping-pong type subgruops which are quasi-isometrically embedded, e.g. in mapping class groups, but the methods of proof that I know involve not-properly-discontinuous-but-otherwise-nice actions of the ambient group (or nondistorted subgroups thereof) on $\delta$-hyperbolic spaces.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, as in Kent-Leininger...

Comment: So the question is about local quasigeodesics ? The title might suggest otherwise.

Comment: @HenrikRüping true, will fix.

Comment: What's the counterexample in the Euclidean plane? It's well known that global quasigeodesics there need not be uniformly close to a geodesic, but that's not quite the same thing...

Comment: @HJRW Well, take a curve made of straight line segments of length $L$ meeting at angle $\pi -\epsilon.$ This will eventually close up into an $2N$-gon (for $\epsilon = \pi/N$), so is not a global quasi-geodesic no matter how large $L$ is, while being a local quasi-geodesic.

Answer (score 1):

Local-to-global results for "Morse quasigeodesics" in symmetric spaces are proven in section 7 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.7671.pdf) that I wrote with Bernhard Leeb and Joan Porti.